# Are personal electronics not allowed in outlets on Cathay Pacific?

Tags: air-travel, electronic-items

> **Please note that personal electronic devices cannot be plugged into
>   the aircraft's utility electrical power supply outlets.** This includes
>   any type of charging devices. An exception is made for portable
>   shavers which may only be used in the appropriate sockets in the
>   lavatories.
>   http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_BH/helpingyoutravel/electronicdevices

What does this really mean? I know that there are AC ports in each seat, but can't these be used for personal electronics. Then what should they be used for?

Comment: The unclear part, to me, is that shavers are said to be an exception, while there are outlets made for that on every plane. The wording is not well chosen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You got it wrong, there are few types of outlets onboard airplanes:

- **Utility outlets:** They are used by the ground/fleet services to clean the aircraft on ground prior to passengers boarding. Usually it will be used for strong vacuum cleaners which requires higher voltage/frequency and can damage electronics not designed for these outlets. **This is the type mentioned in the paragraph you quoted above**.
- **Shavers outlets:** These are found in lavatories, they are designed for electronic shavers and can be used only for shavers.
- **In-seat outlets:** These are embedded in the passengers seats and are designed to be used with personal carry on electronics (laptops, phone chargers...etc). Usually they are deactivated during boarding, take offs and landings and activated during cruise only. This is what you should use and it is available in most major airlines including Cathay Pacific. Also it is mentioned in the [same page you linked](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_BH/helpingyoutravel/electronicdevices):

  > In-seat power will soon be available across our entire fleet for the devices mentioned above. These in-seat power ratings are however not designed for use with medical devices such as CPAP machines. Passengers must provide their own batteries that are sufficient to power medical portable electronic devices.